# The term 'Add-AzureAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I am trying to use this azure commandlets form C# application that is console job hosted in my azure Virtual machine. this job runs more then once in a day automatically but my azure commandlets are fails to execute. yesterday that works fine but after a day it is not working please help me. ☺

**Note** : here i am doing some administration task and i am using organizational account. but it fails to add account other commandlets goes fail to work.

Comment: Can you please let us know how exactly you are trying to connect to azure? Through c# you can use publishsettingfile to connect to azure. Else you can opt Azure runbooks if you are performing some scheduling kind of stuff.

Comment: I am using organizational account to login. 
[you can see here, how i login.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/b2bece71-72d7-4305-ad81-02139959e643/powershell-retrieving-pipeline-errors-in-c?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment)

Answer (score 6):

Install the Azure PowerShell tools. The download link is here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/#how-to-install-azure-powershell

Comment: I installed that Azure Powershell tools to VM. sometime command works fine and sometime not working

Answer (score 4):

It's renamed to Add-AzureAccount.

Comment: How is this different from what the OP has said they are using in the title?

Comment: I suspect the OP edited his question. Now my answer doesn't make sense. Will delete.

Comment: If they had edited it the question would have an "edited" link to the version history.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that the original question was "The term 'Login-AzureRmAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file.   I'm seeing the same thing, despite "Install-Module AzureRM" having been done (from an elevated powershell prompt) and "Get-Module AzureRM" returning a version of 4.3.1 (i.e. powershell tools being installed).

The first part of the solution for me was to also do "Install-Module Azure" (from an elevated powershell prompt) as well after which "Add-AzureAccount" worked.  However a command such as "New-AzureRmResourceGroup" still failed with "Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login".

The second part of the solution was simply to reboot, after which:

```
Add-AzureRmAccount
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name wibble -Location UKSouth
```

worked.